# Multiple values inside array of arrays changing instead of just one value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create an empty array of arrays.

The structure needs to be an array per row (lets say 3) and then x amount of columns per row (lets say 5) for e.g:

```
[
   [false, false, false, false, false],
   [false, false, false, false, false],
   [false, false, false, false, false],
]
```

When `onPress` is clicked on the `TouchableOpacity` component what should happen is that individual column's background gets toggled to red for e.g If I clicked the second column in the second row the array should become this:

```
[
   [false, false, false, false, false],
   [false, true, false, false, false],
   [false, false, false, false, false],
]
```

But what's happening if I do that is this:

```
[
   [false, true, false, false, false],
   [false, true, false, false, false],
   [false, true, false, false, false],
]
```

The second item (or whichever column I click) from every row is getting changed, not the specific column from the specific row. I'm not sure why.

```
export const  = ({
      numberOfRows,
      numberOfCols,
      dimens
    }: Props) => {
      const [rows, setRows] = useState<boolean[][]>(Array(numberOfRows).fill(Array(numberOfCols).fill(false)));
    
      const handleOnPress = (rowIdx: number, colIdx: number) => {
        const rowsData = [...rows];
        rowsData[rowIdx][colIdx] = !rowsData[rowIdx][colIdx];
        setRows(rowsData);
      };
    
      return (
        <View style={{ width: dimens.width, height: dimens.height }}>
          {rows.map((row, rowIdx) => {
            return (
              <View key={Math.random()} style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', marginBottom: 20 }}>
                {row.map((_col, colIdx) => (
                  <TouchableOpacity key={Math.random()} style={{ backgroundColor: rows[rowIdx][colIdx] ? 'red' : '', borderWidth: 1, flex: dimens.width / 5, height: 50 }} onPress={() => handleOnPress(rowIdx, colIdx)}>{colIdx}</TouchableOpacity>
                ))}
              </View>
            );
          })}
        </View>
      );
    };
```

Comment: The array used to fill the rows is the same array; you need a new array for each row. This is noted in the [`Array.fill#value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#value) documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you actually only create two arrays. You create an inner array with **numberOfCols** elements and then an outer array that has **numberOfRows** elements. So all the arrays inside the outer array reference the same array.

So in the initialization of the **rows** state you need to create new array for each row.

```
const [rows, setRows] = useState<boolean[][]>(
    Array(numberOfRows)
    .fill(null)
    .map(_ => Array(numberOfCols).fill(false))
);
```

Comment: Just a remark you are using Math.random() as key which might cause rendering issues so try to create an identical id for your state (in this case you may use the index in the initialization of state).